# How to use ActiveRecord::Base.connection when use raw sql?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Add connection execute in model

```
def self.execute_sql(*sql_array)
  connection.execute(send(:sanitize_sql_array, sql_arry))
end
```

How to close the connection by this case? Is it a good way?

```
def self.close_connection
  connection.close
end
```

By the way, it's a little different from `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute`. Are they the same?

Comment: Assuming defaults, all of your models should be inheriting from `ActiveRecord::Base`, therefore `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute` and your `connection.execute(...)` methods should be exactly the same (minus if you super methods being called). Now, your `execute_sql` method seems to be a bit different that it accepts `*sql_array` argument (which is an Array), which means that the syntax is a bit different than `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute`, because you can now supply sanitized arguments to the SQL: i.e. `User.execute_sql('SELECT * FROM users WHERE created_at > ?, Time.zone.now)`

Comment: Why do you want to close the connections manually? Do you have connection SQL variables?

Comment: @Jay-ArPolidario I'm worried about too many connections issue.

Comment: Just FYI, Rails makes use of [ConnectionPool](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/ConnectionPool.html). So each HTTP request will try to obtain from a Connection in that pool. Rails will not infinitely try to open connections as time goes by. Specify `:pool` size in `database.yml` according to your production needs and DB connections limits. The `:pool` size there is max Connections, and not number of Connections; Rails does not create connections immediately; only by demand.

Comment: However, if you intentionally are not gonna use a Connection for the duration of the Thread / request, and you want to yield back the Connection to the pool immediately, then you can do simply do [`ActiveRecord::Base.release_connection`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/ConnectionPool.html#method-i-release_connection)

Comment: @Jay-ArPolidario Thank you very much for your very useful answer!

Comment: @Jay-ArPolidario You can post that as an answer.

Comment: No prob! Sure; I'll post this an answer :))

Comment: Just a typo in my comment, it should have been `ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.release_connection` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming defaults, all of your models should be inheriting from `ActiveRecord::Base`, therefore `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute` and your `connection.execute(...)` methods should be exactly the same (except only if you super methods being called).

Now, your `execute_sql` method seems to be a bit different that it accepts `*sql_array` argument (which is an Array), which means that the syntax is a bit different than `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute`, because you can now supply sanitized arguments to the SQL: i.e. `User.execute_sql('SELECT * FROM users WHERE created_at > ?, Time.zone.now)`.

Rails makes use of [ConnectionPool](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/ConnectionPool.html). So each HTTP request will try to obtain from a `Connection` in that pool, and when finished the Connection will not be closed but instead will just be returned to that pool. Rails will not infinitely try to open connections as time goes by. Specify `:pool` size in `database.yml` according to your production needs and DB connections limits. The `:pool` size there is max connections, and not number of connections; Rails does not create connections immediately; only by demand.

However, if you intentionally are not gonna use anymore a `Connection` for the duration of the Thread / request, and you want to yield back the `Connection` to the pool immediately, then you can do simply do [`ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.release_connection`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/ConnectionPool.html#method-i-release_connection)